# how to add panels in JFrame

Tags: java, swing, panel

[image]

I don't know what layout should i use and how. thanks.

My frame(rootPanel is BorderLayout):

```
public class MainForm extends JFrame {

    private JPanel rootPanel;

    public MainForm(){
        super("Hello World!");

        setContentPane(rootPanel);


        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(800, 800);

        //Start window from center stream
        Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
        this.setLocation(dim.width / 2 - this.getSize().width / 2, dim.height / 2 - this.getSize().height / 2);
        setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

I need somthing like this. 
[image]
I don't need all of it. Just what lyout should i use and how to place panels correctly?

Comment: Neither do we.  It sort of depends on what you want to display.

Comment: what is the frame in your pic?

Comment: I just want to place panels like on image

Comment: You need to create one, then.  Currently when you `setContentPane(rootPanel);`, your `rootPanel` is `null`.

Comment: @azurefrog it's not null. i'm using Intelij idea and i have rootPanel in Intelij Idea designer

Comment: [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) you can find the most common Layout Managers in Java. The inner panel would be nice with a `FlowLayout`.

Comment: The possible solution can be rather long. So you will probably get a very vague solution here. You may want to narrow down what you want to ask instead of questions like "how to do this?".

Comment: I asked about panels and layouts. What layout should i use to store panels like on first image. But now i understood that first i need to fill the panel with buttons,labels and then to place the panel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I asked about panels and layouts. What layout should i use to store panels like on first image.

From what you have given, it seems fine to me to use FlowLayout which arrange you Components in a direction flow.

You can also add sub-panels within a main panel to arrange your components. Different panels can use different layouts.

**Exmaple:**

[image]

From what you have, you could do something like this. The stated layouts are some possible layouts you could consider using for your panels. The colored boxes are your panels.

[This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html#box) tutorial site indicates quite clearly how each Layout works. You can choose accordingly the layout best suits your scenario.

That's all I can tell you right now from your given question. If you have questions, you can write in the comments.

Comment: ok. thanks i'll use this approach that you recommended. thanks for efforts.
I just thinks that layouts are implemented bad in java swing. Cause i used layouts in android, windows form in c# and they all have better ways to create the UI. What i see in java swing is quite frustrating